# Testing concurrent access in GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, app-engine-ndb

Is it possible to simulate concurrent access to a piece of code in Google App Engine? I am trying to unit test a piece of code that increments a counter. It is possible that the code will be used by different instances of the app concurrently and although I have made the datastore access sections transactional and also used memcache cas I would feel better if there was some way to test it.
I have tried setting up background threads but Testbed seems to be creating a new environment for each thread.

Answer (score 1):

Please vote if it solve your problem :)

GAE works like that:

1. You can have multiple instances of program with separated code space - mean instance has not access to other instance.
2. You can have multiple threads in program instance if you mark code as thread safe - mean each instance has access to same code/memory (counter in you case) - you need locking to avoid conflicts.
3. Memcache is synchronized - updated of value is available to all programs and their threads - there is no concurrent races - mean you can read recent cache value and track if it not change during your changes.

How to simulate concurrent access to piece of code? - You should not simulate you should use clear locking at level of thread or program - since it very hard to simulate concurrent races - it is not know who will win program or thread race since in each environment result is undefined - mean Linux, Windows, Python.

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying. I have wrapped all of my datastore access in transactions and used memcache cas, I suppose I just wanted to test that it would do what I thought it would under load.

Comment: Transaction and cas is very good, consider also use of task if you have random concurrency failures. Consider also thread locking and keeping variables in in context of threads ids/separation - you need separate some global variables at thread level to avoid unpredictable problems.